# Why doesn't my network server on Racket receive data more than once?

Tags: networking, functional-programming, lisp, racket

I'm trying to create a network server on Racket that receives data and does *something* with the data it receives.

The issue that I'm having is that the server only receives something from the client if the client is re-run (clicking the run button). What I really want to do is be able to type (for example) (write "test" out) in the client console as many times as I want and for the server to receive it and process the data in a function on the server file.

Here's my latest attempt at trying to make it work. I'm using echo-server code. But still no luck.

```
(define listener (tcp-listen 3961))

(define (echo-server)
  (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
  (thread (lambda ()
            (print (read in)) 
            (close-output-port out)))
  (echo-server))

(echo-server)
```

Client:

```
(define-values (in out)
  (tcp-connect "localhost" 3961))

(define sendtoserver
      (lambda ()
        (write "test" out)
        (flush-output out)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. The reason why it only prints out "test" once is because you actually close the input port after you read from it once. That means that no more information can be sent from the server.

If instead you did this in a busy loop, aka:

```
(let loop ()
  (print (read in))
  (loop))
```

You would be able to read multiple things. Giving you the following SERVER code.

```
#lang racket

(define listener (tcp-listen 3961))

(define (echo-server)
  (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
  (thread (lambda ()
            (let loop ()
              (print (read in))
              (loop))))
  (echo-server))

(echo-server)
```

Of course, if you did that the server thread would never terminate. So you might want to check for the end of the stream. Something like:

```
#lang racket

(define listener (tcp-listen 3961))

(define (echo-server)
  (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
  (thread (lambda ()
            (let loop ()
              (define val (read in))
              (print val)
              (unless (eof-object? val)
                (loop)))))
  (echo-server))

(echo-server)
```

This does assume that your client will eventually disconnect. Also, this isn't a robust server, as this does still leave it open to many DNS attacks. For information on how to avoid some of them, check out [More: Systems Programming With Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/more/index.html) (provided in the racket docs).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!